# What does cache_time do in telegram's answerCallbackquery API?

Tags: caching, telegram, telegram-bot

The explaination in the  official docs is given as -

`cache_time`    - Integer   Optional. The maximum amount of time in seconds that the result of the callback query may be cached client-side. Telegram apps will support caching starting in version 3.14.
Defaults to 0.

So if someone clicks on the callback button what does sending `cache_time`in `answerCallbackquery` do? I didn't understand the official docs explaination.

Official docs- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery

Answer (score 4):

For example a user has already clicked on an inline button and your bot responded with a message, if that user clicks on the button again within `cache_time`, telegram may show the same message without bothering your server for `cache_time`seconds.

In your last question about limiting user clicks on inline buttons, you can also set cache time to avoid telegram sending callback_query to your server.